# How to clean sesame grains from sandwich toaster effectively?

Tags: cleaning, food

I am using my sandwich toaster to toast bread which often has sesame grains on it. I am also using olive oil to prevent the bread from sticking to the toaster.

This results in such a thing:

[image: Sandwich toaster]

As you can see in the red circles, lots of grains just won't go away when I clean it up, they are stuck in the corners. I prefer not to touch this with my hands, so using paper towels for the cleanup.

Any tips for taking those grains out in some effective way? So far I'm just pulling them one by one with the paper towel, but it's irritating and take lots of time. Shaking the toaster upside down does not work, since the grains are stuck in oil drops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brush should do it - paint, tooth, butter or otherwise, as long as it's sufficiently fine, long, stiff and clean.

Comment: You should edit your first post, not add another answer below.

Comment: @se0D2 no. Each answer is different, with different advice. It's totally legit.

Comment: Best answer so far, didn't think of tooth brush, guess I can have one dedicated to this task, and keep it in the kitchen. Thanks! :)

Comment: It´s not about is it legit; just he can edit first post and improve good answer a bit, no need for two short answers. Anyway, he did it - give helpful answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many young people out there just clean it off with paper.... I will never eat sandwiches from them again, it's very unhygienic...

Instead of using a paper towel, use a kitchen cloth wrung with water and dish soap. Just make sure the cloth isn't dripping wet.
Of course remember to wait until the toaster is **cold** before cleaning.

Alternatively, as the teflon coating has been scratched off, i'd suggest you buy a new one with *removable trays*. They are a bit more expensive, but that will solve your problem for life (you can wash those off like any other dish).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm afraid this does not really answer my actual question. I asked for easier way to remove the grains, doing it with kitchen cloth won't make it any easier. I was not looking for advice about hygiene.

Comment: There are many different kitchen cloths out there, but even the cheaper ones are much better at removing gunk and seends than paper towels.

Yes you will have to (and can) press harder when cleaning, but the task will be over quicker.

Dish soap helps get out the tough stuff...

If you have proper experience with housekeeping this solves the problem perfectly... It also matches the cleaning instructions for 99% of these things...

Answer (score -1):

A piece of sticky tape (cheap Scotch is great) will attach to any seeds and crumbs which are not coated in oil. Use a blunt knife to get into hard-to-reach crevices.

Comment: Not sure about that, don't want to eat from something that came in contact with sticky tape.

Comment: Really? Normal sticky tape doesn't leave any residue.

Comment: Dunno... sometimes I cut it with my teeth and it tastes awful.